# Cerrar o finalizar una clase desde otro activity

Tags: android

tengo esto que me guarda la latitud y la longitud en una base de datos cada 3 min si me voy a otra pantalla de la app se sigue ejecutando y pues quiero cerrarla con un boton y se de deje de guardar
    package com.example.lab_des_06.student;

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ///Esta es la clase del GPS donde muestra los datos de latitud y longitud
    /// y es almacenada en una base de datos de SQLite (por ahora)


    Button btnGPS,bdgps;
    TextView tvUbicacion,tv2,tvmes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        tvUbicacion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvUbicacion);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tvmes  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);

        btnGPS = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGPS);
        bdgps = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bdgps);


        bdgps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,mostrarGPS.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                ejecutar();
            }
        });

        btnGPS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
                                       LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) Main2Activity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                                    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
                                     LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                                     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                                                  // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                                         // Y pues esto se activa cuando se comprobo que el GPS esta activado
                                           // tvmes.setText("Ubicacion actual");
                                             tvUbicacion.setText(" "+location.getLatitude());
                                              tv2.setText(" "+location.getLongitude());
                                             }

                                        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

                                        //Este codigo se activa cuando detecta que el GPS asido activado uwu
                                        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                                            tvmes.setText("Ubicacion actual");
                                           Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "GPS Activado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                   //Este codigo se activa cuando el GPS esta desactivado
                                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                                        tvUbicacion.setText("00");
                                        tv2.setText("00");
                                      tvmes.setText("GPS desactivado");
                                       Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Por favor encienda el GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                      };

                                    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
                                      int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main2Activity.this,
                                             Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                                      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

                                   }
                                                                          }
        );


        //solicitar permisos

       int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main2Activity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                } else {

                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            1);

                    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                    // result of the request.
                }


            }

        }
    }


    //hilos para ejecutar una accion cada cierto tiempo
    public void ejecutar() {
        Tiempo a = new Tiempo();
        a.execute();

    }

    public void hilo() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public class Tiempo extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            hilo();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        DB db= new DB(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
        String ip = tvUbicacion.getText().toString();
        String servidor = tv2.getText().toString();
        String mensaje = db.guardargps(ip, servidor);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mensaje,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ejecutar();

    }

}

}
```

---

tengo esto que me guarda la latitud y la longitud en una base de datos cada 3 min
si me voy a otra pantalla de la app se sigue ejecutando y pues quiero cerrarla con un boton y se de deje de guardar

Comment: Además del código, una breve explicación de que necesitas, dónde y lo que te falla se agradece. Revisa [ask].

Comment: Dónde haces el intent que te lleva a otra activity pones un "finish();" y al cambiar de activity deja esta de ejecutarse .

Answer (score 1):

solo se me ocurre que crees una clase estatica global que reciba como parametro una activity en este caso MainActivity2, luego desde cualquier otra clase recuperas la instancia de esa activity y ladestruyes con el metodo finish(), algo asi:
    public class info {
        static public info instance =null;

```
    public Activity source=null;
    static public info getInstance(){
        if (instance==null){
            instance=new info();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public info() {
        instance.source = source;
    }

    public info(Activity source) {
        instance.source = source;
    }

    public Activity getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(Activity source) {
        this.source = source;
    }
}
```

luego en algun lugar de MainActivity2:
    info.getInstance();
    info.setsource(this);

luego en donde quieras en cualquier activity en tu caso mostrarGPS:

```
info i=info.getInstance();
info.getsource().finish();
```

y listo!!! se finalizara la activity que quieres

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer en este caso es hacerlo como servicio, así puedes implementar en tu Activity principal los botones Iniciar y Finalizar.

MiServicio.java

```
public class registro extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button listo;
private EditText reg_contrasenia,reg_conf_contrasenia, reg_correo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);
    Calligrapher calligrapher = new Calligrapher(this);
    calligrapher.setFont(this,"Hamburg.TTF",true);

    listo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listoBtn);
    reg_contrasenia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etReg_Contrasenia);
    reg_conf_contrasenia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etReg_Conf_contrasenia);
    reg_correo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCorreo);


    listo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (reg_correo.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(registro.this, "Correo vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(reg_contrasenia.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(registro.this, "Contraseña vacía", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(reg_contrasenia.getText().toString().equals(reg_conf_contrasenia.getText().toString())){
                startActivity(new Intent(registro.this,ingreso.class));
                Toast.makeText(registro.this, "Registro exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(registro.this, "Contraseñas no coinciden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });

}
```

En el MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button bInicia, bPara;
TextView tvCoor;
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
int ha = 1;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(broadcastReceiver == null){
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Intent.getExtras().get("latitud");


            }
        };
    }
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("cambio_latitud"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(broadcastReceiver != null){
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    bInicia = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bInicia);
    bPara = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bPara);
    tvCoor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCoor);

    if(!runtime_permissions())
        habilitar_botones();

}
    private void habilitar_botones(){
    bInicia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MiServicio.class);
            startService(i);

            //ha = ha +1;

        }
    });


    bPara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ha = ha -1;
            tvCoor.setText("Detenido");
            Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MiServicio.class);
            stopService(i);


        }
    });
    }

private boolean runtime_permissions() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},100);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == 100){
        if( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            habilitar_botones();
        }else {
            runtime_permissions();
        }
    }
}
```

Este es un código que alguna vez hice para pruebas, así que tiene algunas cosas que corregir, pero el concepto es el mismo.

Answer (score -1):

Veo que deseas finalizar una clase desde otro activity. En realidad lo que debes realizar es finalizar la Activity cuando cambias a una nueva Activity, mediante el método `finish()`

```
 bdgps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,mostrarGPS.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                ejecutar();

                finish(); //*Finaliza actual Activity.

            }
        });
```

> [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) Se llama cuando su actividad esté completa y deba
>   cerrarse.

Comment: gracias pero ese boton se precionaria despues osea ese boton se debe precionar ya que llegue a mi destino, mientras yo puedo seguir haciendo mas cosas de la app, a lo que voy es que no necesariamente se debe finalizar al salir de esa pantalla a la otra, si no que ese boton lo precione y me deje ahi donde mismo . no se si me explique bien